# jQuery ajax call to php giving a 404 not found: what am I missing?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery Ajax call to php giving a 404 not found.  What am I missing?
Requesting the page (non Ajax) from a browser gives me the json data back.

The jQuery calling the php by Ajax:

```
$.post({
    url:'/jqgrid/nwproducts.php',

    success:function(data){
        $('#auto').autocomplete({source:data.ProductName});
    }
});
```

The php code:

```
    <?php
header("Content-Type: application/json"); 
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

$arrayProduct = array();
$mysqli =  new mysqli('localhost','login','passwd','northwind');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$resultAll = $mysqli->query('select ProductName from products');

if (!$resultAll)
{
    echo "error\n";
} else {
    while ($obj = $resultAll->fetch_object()) {
    array_push($arrayProduct,$obj);
    }


echo json_encode($arrayProduct);
}
?>
```

I am getting the following error in firebug:

```
http://localhost/jqgrid/%5Bobject%20Object%5D 404 Not Found
```

Comment: well, a 404 means that no page was found at your `/jqgrid/nwproducts.php` URL ... I'd start investigating if I can actually access my PHP file from there.

Comment: What is the full URL for `/jqgrid/nwproducts.php` and the URL from which do you call that ajax? Perhaps base does not put the absolute path correctly, cause 404 could not be PHP error, it is incorrect URL. Trace the URL the ajax really calls.

Comment: the url is correct browsing to it give me an array of json objects; not sure what the %5Bobject%20Object in the error in the url I get back means

Comment: You are using the method `post` in a wrong way, see [Yuri](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8937941/554761)'s answer; or use lower-level function `.ajax` instead of `.post`

Comment: `http://localhost/jqgrid/%5Bobject%20Object%5D`  does not look good - have you checked how this URL was built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Pranay I used your code modified a little bit but it worked

```
(function IsExists(pagePath) {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: pagePath,
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 alert(textStatus);
             },
             success:function(result) {
                             $('#auto').autocomplete({source:result});
                                }
         });
     })('/jqgrid/nwproductsonly.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

Put out `url` and `success` param off the object.

```
$.post('/jqgrid/nwproducts.php', function(data) {
  $('#auto').autocomplete({source:data.ProductName});
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

If possible, check whether the page is accessible and whether you provided the correct page URL.

One more solution: if possible make use of an Ajax function that gives you more flexibility.

```
 function IsExists(pagePath, dataString) {
         //alert(pagePath);

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: pagePath,
             data: dataString,
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 alert(textStatus);

             },
             success:
                                function(result) {
                                    var flg = true;
                                    if (result != null) {

                                        flg = result.d;

                                        if (flg == "True") {
                   alert('Success-true');                                            }
                                        else {
                 alert('Success - false');                                            }
                                    }
                                }
         });

     }
```